# second level menu appear when parent or child is active wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like my sub menu items to show up when both the parent is active and the current menu or any other child of that parent is active on my wordpress website. I got it so that the two children show up when the parent is active, but they go away when you click on any of the children

Example: https://vfcasino.com/dining/fine-dining/

Viviano and Pacific Prime show up when you're on the Fine Dining page, but then go away when you click on the parent page. I don't want them to appear if you are on Casual Dining or Bars & Lounges. I want them to appear on Fine Dining, Viviano or Pacific Prime.

Here is the css I am using:

```html
#sidebar .widget.widget_nav_menu ul li ul{
display:none; 
}

#sidebar .widget.widget_nav_menu li.current_page_item > ul, 
#sidebar .widget_nav_menu li.current-menu-ancestor > ul ,
.widget.widget_nav_menu li.current_page_item > ul,
.widget_nav_menu li.current-menu-ancestor > ul
{display:block; padding-left:20px; padding-bottom: 10px;}
```

I have tried manipulating the css, but I just cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this should work:

```
#sidebar .widget_nav_menu .current-page-ancestor > .sub-menu {
display: block;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

You just need to override this selector with more precise selector for the sub-menu:

```
#sidebar .widget.widget_nav_menu ul li ul {
display: none;
}
```